# Zend framework : Cannot access database configuration through application.ini

Tags: zend-framework

I am new to Zend. The problem i am getting is that i am not able to access resources.db.* configurations from application.ini
The way i am using to access is

```
$application->getOptions()
```

. It does not shows the resource.db.* properties.

Can any one help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead

```
$params = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter()->getConfig(); //return associative array
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it the way you asked about, the easiest way I've found is to put everything in the registry during bootstrap:

```
//bootstrap.php
public function _initConfig {
   $config = new Zend_Config($this->getOptions());
   Zend_Registry::set('config', $config);
}
```

to use these configs elsewhere in your application:

```
$db = Zend_Registry::get('config')->resources->db;
```

although if you are just trying to access the adapter registered in the application.ini:

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
```